# Absolute vertical and horizontal center text in responsive div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, center

I am really stuck trying to figure this out - I am attempting to both vertically and horizontally text in a responsive div that appears over an image on hover.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1harbqm/1/) of the basic HTML and CSS structure.

[Here's an example of what I'm attempting to do.](http://cl.ly/bJNm?_ga=1.13000183.1598941667.1433081947)

I've tried many different CSS methods - using `table` (which can't work since I'm using `absolute` to have the text above the image, `transform: translate(-50%, -50%); top: 50%; left: 50%;` which offsets the text, and others that I'm not recalling at the moment.

**The main issue is that I have two "layers" - the text and an image below it. In order to do that I need to use `absolute` which causes the `table` option to not work.**

I'd really appreciate any suggestions you might have.

**Note:** the image I'm using must retain a 16:9 aspect ratio.

Thank you!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: if you want to venture try css flexbox

Comment: @Vaune_X I tried all of the solutions on that page. None have worked properly.

Comment: @NikosM. I just updated my post with an image of what I'm trying to do. Would flexbox work for that?

Comment: @Connor, see my posted answer and links therein, feel free to comment if further info is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/v1harbqm/7/

I based it off @gopalraju's fiddle. It wasn't working in Safari, but a combination of `display: table;` and adding a height to the heading works.

**Edit**: Created a `<span>` within the title to get it to work with longer text. Using translate this time, and it looks like Safari still needs the -webkit- prefix so that might've been the original problem to begin with.

Anyway, here's the updated one: https://jsfiddle.net/v1harbqm/13/

Comment: This actually doesn't seem to work once the text is more than one line long. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jruvcogm/

```
.work{
    display:table;
}    
.work a{
    position:relative;display:table;
}    
.work h1{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin:0;
    width:80%;
    text-align:center;
}    
.work img{
    width:800px;
    height:450px;
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this isn't working properly for me and even the jsfiddle link isn't working :( thank you though

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle and post, so that I can review.

Comment: I just updated the post with an image of what I'm trying to achieve. I'll also make a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/v1harbqm/2/

Comment: Is that working for you? [Here's what I see when I visit your link.](http://cl.ly/bJt6?_ga=1.17134969.1598941667.1433081947)

Answer (score 0):

posting css code for centering horizontaly and/or verticaly things with pure css
(adapted from my `responsive.css` script). Includes references to online sources. Use as needed. **Note** you may need to adjust your html structure a bit for some cases to include a wrapper (see comments)

```
/* center alignment classes */
/* http://www.dev-metal.com/center-div-vertically-horizontally-modern-method-without-fixed-size/ */
.center-vertical-wrapper
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.center-horizontal-wrapper
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.center-h
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.center-contents-h
{
    text-align: center;
}
/* http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/#Height */
.center-absolute /* needs width/height to be set */
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float:left;
    margin: auto;
}
.center-transform /* needs width/height to be set */
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
/* http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/ */
.center-flexbox 
{
    display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
    display: -moz-box;      /* OLD: Firefox (buggy) */ 
    display: -ms-flexbox;   /* MID: IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;  /* NEW, Chrome 21–28, Safari 6.1+ */
    display: flex;          /* NEW: IE11, Chrome 29+, Opera 12.1+, Firefox 22+ */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% /* needed for Firefox */
}
```